# How to automatically associate DropBox folder with the theme?

Tags: themes, icons, directory, dropbox

In Faenza & Faience icon themes there is a dropbox icon for the folder of DropBox, but if I set my icons theme to one of theme nothing happens to the folder. So, I have to change the icon of the folder manually.

How can I associate the DropBox folder to use the icon "folder-dropbox.svg" with any theme automatically?

Also can I do the same thing for my created folders? I want to create a folder called Projects and associate it with the icon "stock_bookmark.svg" of any theme.

Note: I do not want the manual way of doing so (Using: Folder's Properties->Basic->Custom Icon)

Comment: That Icon has never worked I don't know why it is still there. "I want to create a theme called Projects and associate it with the icon "stock_bookmark.svg" of any theme." - You mean a *folder* not a theme?.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only way to do this, is to set a custom icon. The dropbox folder is not treated specially by the system, and so there is no way for the system to know what icon name to use. Any themes that include the icon, do so as a matter of convenience, and not because it will "just work" with the system.

Comment: Is there a way to make the system treat a folder specially? eg: Dropbox folder

Comment: There is not, other than to write code. And doing it correctly may involve adding API, and fixing the Nautilus extension for Dropbox to use the new API, so that it would only work on newer systems where that API is provided, and the extension is built to use it.

Comment: How does the system treat default user's folders specially? Cannot we apply the same way?

Comment: They are treated specially because they are part of a specification which specifically denotes them as special, and the code is written to handle them specially. To handle per-app things specially, you would need a generic way to do it. It involves writing a bunch of code. There is no setting or such you could change to make it work.